# HTML5 layout control (or form) builder, similar to WPF DXLayoutControl

Tags: angularjs, html, layout, devexpress, formbuilder

I'm searching for HTML5 layout control builder, I searched the web for suitable products but it seems that the only examples include only fields chaining e.g.: 
http://kelp404.github.io/angular-form-builder/

The problem I need 3 more important features:

1. Creating tabs
2. Group fields
3. Multi-column layout

In WPF I'm using DXLayoutControl of DevExpress (https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/Layout/layout_control.xml) and I would be happy to find an equivalent in HTML5

[image]

It is important to clarify that I need a designer, meaning the end user will build the layout and it will generate a JSON output result of the layout.